# How to get 50 links of result using RBing?

Tags: ruby, bing-api

I'm making a program using RBing.
But I unable to get 50 links.
How can I get those?

Thanks!

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rbing'
MultiJson.engine = :ok_json
bing = RBing.new("APP_ID")
query = "Cat"
results = bing.web("#{query}", :offset=>0, :count=>50)
puts results.web.total
for num in 0..49 do
  puts num
  puts results.web.results[num].title
  puts results.web.results[num].url
  puts results.web.results[num].description
  puts ""
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Microsoft Bing API. I tried several queries and received the result as follows:

> http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?sources=Web&query=Belarus&AppId=MYAPPID

returned `"Total":78800000`

But when I add `Web.offset=0&Web.count=50` and make request

> http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?sources=Web&Web.offset=0&Web.count=50&query=Belarus&AppId=MYAPPID

I get `"Total":35`

Please fill support request to Microsoft and let us know about results.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer.
I will wait a little bit more. :)